# Laravel job ModelNotFoundException when dispatching from controller and running

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with one of my Laravel 8 API project's that I've built where a user is able to add a domain to their account. The domain needs to be crawled to obtain expiration dates etc and is available in the user's account.

This process takes some time and so I've extracted the logic that fetches the domain data into a job called `DomainExpiryChecker`.

When a new domain is added, a job is dispatched, but may not execute straight away, and in some cases the user may even delete the domain before the job runs.

For some reason, even after dispatching my job after a record has been made, I'm getting the following failed job error and I'm not sure what I'm missing:

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model [App\Models\Domains]

My controller where the job is dispatched resembles the following:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Domains;
use Carbon\Carbon;

use App\Jobs\DomainExpiryChecker;

class DomainsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new DomainsController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Add a new domain
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function add(Request $request)
    {

        $domain = new Domains();
        $domain->domain = '';
        $domain->crawled = 'pending';
        $domain->has_valid_ssl = false;
        $domain->user_id = Auth::id();
        $domain->save();

        // on-demand
        if ($domain) {
          DomainExpiryChecker::dispatch($domain)->onQueue('on-demand-runs-now');
        }

        // everything went okay!
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message' => "Added $domain_name successfully, please allow between 24 and 48 hours for crawling"], 201);

    }

}
```

Whilst my job looks like the following:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

use App\Models\Settings;
use App\Models\Domains;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class DomainExpiryChecker implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The domain instance.
     */
    protected $domain;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($domain)
    {
        $this->domain = $domain;
    }

    /**
    * Get single domain
    *
    * @return object
    */
    public function getDomain($domain)
    {
        $domain = Domains::where('id', $domain['id'])
                         ->first();

        return $domain;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        $updatableDomain = $this->getDomain($this->domain);

        if (!$updatableDomain) {
          return;
        }

        // stuff happens here

    }
}
```

What am I missing, I'm sure it's just one thing.

Comment: Shouldn't  `$domain['id']` be `$domain->id` in your job?

Comment: Nope, because `$this->domain` passes the domain into the `getDomain` function, but this isn't related to my question :)